# How to create a non-responsive WordPress Theme Using Genesis Framework?

Tags: child-theme, genesis-theme-framework, responsive, remote, customization

I am new to coding and I really don't know how to create a non-responsive child theme which runs on the Genesis framework. Besides that, I tried to modify a child theme and it all went well but one day when i tried to re-size the browser window i noticed that the theme was all messed up and looked ugly. I really want to know whether it is possible to remove the responsiveness from a Genesis child theme or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all the CSS code under the Media Queries section of any child theme built on Genesis. This code is generally located at the end of the style.css file.

However, WordPress also includes responsiveness built in so its not really possible to totally remove everything unless you go to a lot of trouble.

If you remove all the Media Queries, you will find your site will not look good when re-sized so its not a good idea to remove any CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now i have to learn the responsive UI. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can with the Genesis Framework by setting the width

```
#wrap {width:960px;}
```

and remove all viewport css.

Note: Do this on child theme.

I read this on a developer's forum.